# Folders/files structure for nuxt Dynamic routes

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

How should files and folders be structured so that url would be like this : `localhost:3000/apps/10/ads/12`
10 and 12 are ids of a selected app and a selected ad.

so far with folder structure below I get this url :

`localhost:3000/apps/10/`

how should I edit folder structure to get the whole url work?

Folder structure:

```
pages/
---|apps/
-----|index.vue
-----|_id.vue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use an "_id" schema name for a folder too.

eg. with `_app` & `_ad`:

```
pages/
---|apps/
-----|index.vue
-----|_app/
-------|index.vue     # localhost:3000/apps/10
-------|ads/
---------|_ad.vue     # localhost:3000/apps/10/ads/12
```

or

```
...
-------|ads/
---------|_ad/
-----------index.vue  # localhost:3000/apps/10/ads/12
```